# Web Application with Back4App database

Tags: android, asp.net, database, codeigniter, back4app

I develop an android application with Back4App database.
Now I want to develop an Admin Panel for the Application.

Back4App is the central Database of my project.
It is Object Oriented.

So Which one is the best option to develop an Admin Panel of my android app.
Admin Panel is in Web.

1. Asp.Net with Back4app
2. Codeigniter with Back4app
3. Core PHP with Back4app.
4. Any other, Your Best Suggestion?

Answer (score 1):

Back4App is powered by Parse Open Source and the SDKs available to use are:

- iOS
- Android
- Javascript
- .NET + Xamarin
- MacOS
- Unity
- PHP
- Arduino
- and use REST API ...

Check more information [here](https://docs.parseplatform.org).

Just to show you more options... The Back4App offers examples to use Node.JS environment or JS frameworks, they're:

- [Ionic Template](https://www.back4app.com/docs/ionic/ionic-templates)
- [React Template](https://www.back4app.com/docs/react/react-native-template)
- [Angular Template](https://www.back4app.com/docs/javascript/angular-template)

And the good point is that you can use the Back4App subdomain to host your web application, but the options that you sent are great too.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned Asp.Net in 1 the closest thing to it would be Xamarin, I guess..

You could bridge B4A somehow with PHP like in 2 & 3 but it is a lot easier to work with the technologies Back4App offer out of the box, right?

So 4 my best suggestion is to go with node/express/react. It is what I`m doing.